# How to update the range in powerpoint chart from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I run a VBA script from an excel workbook which also holds all data. The script automatically updates a chart in excel if I add new datapoints. However when I put the same chart in powerpoint it no longer updates when new data points are added.

I have tried using various linked versions of charts. One of them does the job but then it is only an image in powerpoint and I need the actual chart to be  updated when I run the VBA script.

In the code below I try to access the powerpoint chart directly and just update it's range. I have tried various versions of this but can't get it to work. It opens the powerpoint and identifies the shape but can't change the range.

```
Dim PPTApp As Object
Dim PPTPres As Object
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApp.Visible = True

Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Open("file:///C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\pptest111.pptx")
PPTPres.Windows(1).Activate

PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1").Chart.ChartData.Sheets("sht2").Range ("A5:A15")
```

Comment: Note that PowerPoint can update charts automatically without using VBA: [Automatic Updating of Excel Tables in PowerPoint Slides](https://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/automatic-updating-of-excel-tables-in-powerpoint-slides/)

Comment: I know, but then it becomes an image. I need a standard chart in the powerpoint presentation that other users are familiar with and can interact with. In other words: click on it, change colors etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the range of a chart you have to change the range of the labels and data.

XValues is the range for labels and values is the range for data

if oSh is PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1")

Then some variant of this should work

```
  oSH.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "sht2!$A$5:$A15"  ' change the series range for labels
  oSH.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).values = "sht2!$B$5:$B15"   ' change the series range for data
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly using your suggestion! For anyone struggling with this, just use the solution above. This will give you an empty chart in powerpoint. This chart however is adjusted with the new range so just add one line updating the chart with the code below and it works perfectly, PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1").LinkFormat.Update

Answer (score 0):

mooseman answers works but you need to update chart AfterWords. For me the LinkFormat.Update was not picking up any shape so i added this to resolve it

```
With oSH.Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Workbook.Close
End With
```